# html input field should allow only numbers and between 2 and 50 only

Tags: regex, html

my HTML input field should allow only numbers between 2 and 50 and my html code is below and it's still allowing me to enter unlimited digits. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<input type="number" min="2" max="50" pattern="[0-9]*">
```

Comment: `min="2"` and `max="50"` will only be enforced when you submit the form, not when typing into it. `pattern="[0-9]*"` I believe means any number of digits 0 through 9.

Comment: If you want the input limited as the user enters it, then you'd need to use JavaScript

Comment: You can't use `pattern` with type `number`

Comment: Now I have modified the pattern to "^2?[0-9]?[0-9]$|^(50)$" and it's correctly validating the value to be between 2 and 50 after tabbing out of the field, but the input box is not restricting me to enter more than 2 digits. Also as this field should display number pad iphone Safari I am using type="number" pattern combination.

Comment: Try `^([2-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)$`. See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iiLVhi/2)

Comment: As @revo said, can't use pattern on input type number, you must convert to type text if you want to use pattern. https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/number  ||  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Comment: the following works: <input type="text" pattern="^([2-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)$">    thank you!

btw, how do i make the field displaying numeric keypad when opened the portal on mobile browsers like safari?